# Minimizing a non-convex rational function of two variables

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

I need to minimize the following function 
$$f(x,y)= \frac{a}{x}+\frac{bx}{y}+\frac{cy}{x}+dy+\frac{e}{y}$$
where $a,b,c,d$, and $e$ are positive constants, and $x$ and $y$ are both strictly positive.

I believe the best way is to prove that $f(x,y)$ pseudoconvex, or invex? (I could not do this).  However, This is what I have been to:

- From the Hessian matrix, the function is not convex for all possible values of $a,b,c,d$, and $e$.
- Setting the gradient of $f(x,y)$ to $0$ gives a unique solution of x and y.
- I also noticed that the function goes to infinity when $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $x\to\infty$ or $y\to\infty$.

Hence I conclude that the stationary point is global minimum

1. Can you help me characterize the function? (pseudoconvex, invex ..?)
2. What do you think of my approach? is it valid?

Comment: What do you get when plugging the unique critical point into the Hessian matrix? BTW I reformatted the formulas. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a geometric program. Let $x = e^u$, $y=e^v$, then the function is convex in $u$ and $v$.